# Related Nodes with exposed Filter that share all / multiple terms

Tags: 7, views

Here is my problem: I have several nodes tagged with multiple terms. I want to display related nodes based on these terms in a block. I followed the main instructions that one can find as this: http://scito.ch/content/show-related-nodes-block-based-taxonomy-terms-views-3-and-drupal-7

Everything works okay but even if I choose "Filter to items that share **all** terms" only a matching on "any terms" seems to be made by Drupal. Here is my setting:

Node 1

- category: sunglasses
- color: yellow
- gender: male

Node 2

- category: sunglasses
- color: red
- gender: male

Node 3

- category: jeans
- color: blue
- gender: female

Node 4

- category: jeans
- color: red
- gender: male

Node 5

- category: shoes
- color: yellow
- gender: male

As result I want for "node 1" only "node 2" to be displayed as a related node based on category and gender. Because category and gender hit my filter so it's an AND combination.

In my current problem I see all nodes that would hit on an OR combination. Here is my views setting:

[image: Problem filter]

All common problems that one can find on this topic seem not to be my problem. Anyone that can help?

Thanks a lot!!